# Unable to connect to w3wp.exe or aspnet_wp.exe Process

Tags: asp.net

we have developed  web application with web services and added on IIS pool

But when another user is trying to access this application using IP Address he unable to access the application while it is hosted on IIS Successfully 
But giving error

> "The Connection has timed out"

Comment: Can u check if firewall is not blocking the connections and your site is publically accessible?

Comment: What it has to do with w3wp?